# Shell spawned backgrounded process is still hanging

Tags: bash

It seems processes spawned after `||` make the parent shell hang with them.
For example, do in your terminal

```
$ cat <<"EOF" >/tmp/hello_im_still_here
#!/usr/bin/env bash
killall emacsclient
pgrep emacsclient || emacsclient -c &
EOF
$ chmod +x /tmp/hello_im_still_here
$ ./tmp/hello_im_still_here
```

and check it

```
$ pstree | grep emacsc
     |-hello_im_still_---emacsclient
```

Changing the line forking the process to

```
pgrep emacsclient || (nohup emacsclient -c) &
```

doesn’t help.

Comment: How is it "hanging"? What's your actual question?

Comment: Agree with @terdon - the shell isn't hanging.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @terdon, one shell process is _hanging_, see the `hello_im_still` in the pstree output. Please allow the OP a few hours to address the questions before closing.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I can't reproduce this, I see no hung process in pstree. Could this depend on other settings? Also, as soon as the OP (or anyone else) edits the question it will be nominated for reopening so closing is not that drastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` and most shells, contrary to `zsh`,

```
cmd1 || cmd2 &
```

is like:

```
{ cmd1 || cmd2; } &
```

So it's that subshell running `cmd1 || cmd2` that is started in background.

`bash` does not optimise by executing `cmd2` in the subshell process which is why you see two processes: the `bash` and `cmd2` process. The `bash` process is just waiting for `cmd2` to terminate. Note that the calling shell is not blocked. The only *"problem"* is that extra unnecessary subshell process and the fact that `cmd1` is also run in background.

Use:

```
cmd1 || { cmd2 &}
```

Or more legibly:

```
if ! cmd1; then
  cmd2 &
fi
```

If you only want `cmd2` run in background.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, I just didn’t think of application of curly brackets in this manner. Also I’d like to point one thing though `{cmd1 || cmd2; } &` does the same it is not because curly brackets create a subshell, they only combine commands in a list _in the current shell_, i.e. in this example they actually do nothing. As far as I understand thanks to your answer, it’s just a feature of `&` to fork the entire string with `||`. I’ve read earlier somewhere that bash creates a subshell for the left part of `||` statement, thus it all has been forked to background in my code from OP.

Comment: @tijagi, adding a `&` to a compound command in `bash` creates a subshell (it has to to run in background as that means running in a different process. `{...;} &` is equivalent to `(...)&` in that  case), my use of `{...;}` was to show how the grouping works. `&` puts the whole `list` in background. `||` doesn't cause subshells, you must be confusing with `|`.

Comment: Yes, exactly.­­